# Django: strange reverse match

Tags: python, django

In my app, I've got a view which generates a form. When this form is valid the view redirect to another view which is another form, but I have an error message with the reverse match.

My views.py:

```
def uploadData(request, dataType, method):
    if method == 'single':
        if dataType == 'Sequence-has-SNP':
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SeqHasSnpForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    idSequence = form.cleaned_data['seq_linked']
                    return redirect('addSNPsSeq', idSequence)
            else:
                form = SeqHasSnpForm()
            return render(request, 'myapp/upload_sequence-has-snp.html', locals())
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...


def uploadSNPsToSeq(request, idSequence):
    seq = Sequence.objects.get(PK_idSequence = idSequence)
    thisSeqHasSnp = Seq_has_SNP.objects.filter(FK_idSequence = seq.PK_idSequence)
    snpAll = SNP.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectSNPsForSeqForm(request.POST, snps=snpAll, seqHasSnps=thisSeqHasSnp)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Yeaaahhh!')
    else:
        form = SelectSNPsForSeqForm(snps=snpAll, seqHasSnps=thisSeqHasSnp)
        print(form)
    return render(request, 'myapp/SNPs-to-add-to-sequence.html', locals())
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^SNPs-to-add-to-sequence_(?P<idSequence>.+)$', views.uploadSNPsToSeq, name='addSNPsSeq'),
    url(r'^upload_(?P<dataType>[A-Za-z-]+)_(?P<method>(single|batch))$', views.uploadData, name='upload'),
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home') 
]
```

I have my 2 templates called `upload_sequence-has-snp.html` and `SNPs-to-add-to-sequence.html`.

The 2 forms are OK because I have access to my first form and for example select a `form.cleaned_data['seq_linked']` equal to `TEST`. I can see the result in the terminal of `print(form)` in `uploadSNPsToSeq`, but the last line of this view raise a `NoReverseMatch error`:

```
NoReverseMatch at /myapp/SNPs-to-add-to-sequence_TEST

Reverse for 'upload' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myapp/upload_(?P<dataType>[A-Za-z-]+)_(?P<method>(single|batch))$']
```

I don't understand why is it looking for `myapp/upload_...` instead of `myapp/SNPs-to-add-to-sequence_...` ?

Any clue?

Comment: Your template `myapp/SNPs-to-add-to-sequence.html` (or a template that it extends) contains `{% url 'upload' ... %}`. This is failing because the variables are not set in the template context and are evaluating to `('', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alasdair! That was the issue.

So in my views.py I replaced `idSequence` by `dataType`, added `method` as parameters for my `uploadSNPsToSeq` function and in the urls.py changed the url pattern for this view.

views.py:

```
def uploadData(request, dataType, method):
    if method == 'single':
        if dataType == 'Sequence-has-SNP':
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SeqHasSnpForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    dataType = form.cleaned_data['seq_linked']
                    return redirect('addSNPsSeq', dataType, method)
            else:
                form = SeqHasSnpForm()
            return render(request, 'myapp/upload_sequence-has-snps.html', locals())
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...

def uploadSNPsToSeq(request, dataType, method):
    seq = Sequence.objects.get(PK_idSequence = dataType)
    thisSeqHasSnp = Seq_has_SNP.objects.filter(FK_idSequence = seq.PK_idSequence)
    snpAll = SNP.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectSNPsForSeqForm(request.POST, snps=snpAll, seqHasSnps=thisSeqHasSnp)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Yeaaahhh!')
    else:
        form = SelectSNPsForSeqForm(snps=snpAll, seqHasSnps=thisSeqHasSnp)
    return render(request, 'myapp/upload_snps-for-sequence.html', locals())
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload_snps-for-sequence_(?P<dataType>[A-Za-z-]+)_(?P<method>(single|batch))$', views.uploadSNPsToSeq, name='addSNPsSeq'),
    url(r'^upload_(?P<dataType>[A-Za-z-]+)_(?P<method>(single|batch))$', views.uploadData, name='upload'),
    ...
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home') 
]
```